# Converting a main to objects and importing a randNum[]

Tags: java, object, program-entry-point

I have wrote code that functions properly. I calculates the max, min, median, mode, mean, and standard dev. This is all calculated from a random number generator.  I want to clean up the main (I did not know this was an option at the time) by making all of these functions different objects.

I need the number generator in the new main and I do not know how to call that to the new class. I have tried to use "get", but I do not know if you can use the get method for an array.

The first block of code is what I want to convert into objects. The second is my attempt to do so. The third is the new main is only has the random number generator I know it is not printing anything out.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;

class StatisticsMain {
  public static void main (String[] args) {


    int SIZE = 100; // the number of random #'s generated
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int[] nums = new int[SIZE];
    for (int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++) {
      nums[q] = rand.nextInt (490) + 10; // only numbers from 10-500 generated

    }
    // System.out.println (Arrays.toString (nums));

     Arrays.sort (nums); // organizes numbers for max min and median
     double median;
     if(nums.length % 2 == 0){
       median = ((double)nums[nums.length/2] 
         + (double)nums[nums.length/2 - 2])/2;
     }else {
         median = (double)nums[nums.length/2];
         }

     System.out.println("The Min number is: \t "+ nums[0]); //  Min 
     System.out.println("The Max number is:\t " + nums[99]); // Max
     System.out.println("The Median is: \t " + median); // Median


    //==============================================================
    //--------------------------- MEAN------------------------------
    double sum= 0 ;
    double  mean = 0 ;
    for(double w : nums){
    sum += w;
    mean = sum/SIZE;    }

    System.out.println("The Mean is:\t " + mean);

    //==============================================================
    //----------------------------MODE------------------------------
     //count the occurrences
    for (int e=0; e < nums.length; e++) {
        nums[e]++;
    }

    //go backwards and find the count with the most occurrences
    int mode = nums.length-1;
       for (int e= nums.length-2; e >=0; e--) 
       {
        if (nums[e] >= nums[mode])
          System.out.println( "The Mode is: \t " +  (mode = e));

        else 
          System.out.println("The Mode is:\t -1");
           break;
       }
     //==============================================================
     //-------------------------Standard Deviation-------------------  

     double val = 0,adding = 0, divide = 0, answer = 0, square= 0 ;
        for ( double r : nums){ 
          val =   r- mean;
          square  = val* val;
          adding += square ;
          divide = adding /100;
          answer = Math.sqrt(divide);

      }
          System.out.println("The Stand. Dev. is: \t " + answer); // standard deviation

     //=================================================================     

    }
  }









//===================================================//
//    NEXT CODE            NEXT CODE       NEXT CODE //
//===================================================//

class Statistics
{
Main nums1 = new Main();
Main [] nums = num1.getNums();

  Main nums = new Main();
public static double mean(nums[]) {
    double sum= 0 ;
    double  mean = 0 ;
    for(double w : nums[]){
    sum += w;
    mean = sum/SIZE;    }

    return mean;
}

public static double mode(nums[])
{

     for (int e=0; e < nums.length; e++) {
        nums[e]++;
    }

    //go backwards and find the count with the most occurrences
       int mode = nums.length-1;
       for (int e= nums.length-2; e >=0; e--) 
       {
        if (nums[e] >= nums[mode])
          // System.out.println( "The Mode is: \t " +  (mode = e));
          mode = e;

        else 
          mode = -1;
          //System.out.println("The Mode is:\t -1");
         return mode;
       }
}

public double median(nums[])
{
     double median;
     if(nums.length % 2 == 0){
         median = ((double)nums[nums.length/2] 
         + (double)nums[nums.length/2 - 2])/2;
     }else {
         median = (double)nums[nums.length/2];
         }
     return median;
}
public int Max(nums[])
{
  Max = nums[99];
  return Max;
}

public int Min(nums[])
{
  Min = nums[0];
  return Min;
}


public double StanDev(nums[])
{
  double val = 0,adding = 0, divide = 0, answer = 0, square= 0 ;
        for ( double r : nums){ 
          val =   r- mean;
          square  = val* val;
          adding += square ;
          divide = adding /100;
          answer = Math.sqrt(divide);

      } return answer;
}
}






//===================================================//
//    NEXT CODE            NEXT CODE       NEXT CODE //
//===================================================//



import java.util.*;


public class Main
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {

    int SIZE = 100; // the number of random #'s generated
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int[] nums = new int[SIZE];
    for (int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++) {
    nums[q] = rand.nextInt (400) + 10; // only numbers from 10-500 generated
    Arrays.sort (nums); // organizes numbers for max min and median
    }


    public int getNums () 
  {
    return nums ;
  }


    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to convert the code into separate objects, merely into separate methods, similar to the `Math` class that has many methods for mathematical calculations. And then you pass the data for the calculation as parameters to these methods, and get the results through the return value.

Comment: @austinwernli No.  [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) is for code that functions properly, yes, but it's also for when you're looking for a review of that code--not for when you're looking to add functionality to existing code that just happens to work correctly.  Please read more than the first sentence of a post before recommending it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @RealSkeptic Are they not already methods ?    Arrays.sort (nums); // organizes numbers for max min and median
     double median;
     if(nums.length % 2 == 0){
       median = ((double)nums[nums.length/2] 
         + (double)nums[nums.length/2 - 2])/2;
     }else {
         median = (double)nums[nums.length/2];
         }                                                                                                                          Median is a method correct ?

Comment: A method is a piece of code you can call using a name and parameters and receive a result. Imagine your class is called `Stats`, then you would be able to call `double x = Stats.mean(nums)` and you'll get the mean of that array, and you'll be able to call it with different sets of data in the same way. Currently you just have chunks of code without name, parameters or a way to call them separately.